# How to repair or ignore corrupted blocks in oracle in noarchivelog mode

Tags: oracle, rman

I have a table with partitioned by date. Today when I run query for entire month I get following error:

```
SQL Error [1578] [72000]: ORA-01578: ORACLE data block corrupted (file # 10, block # 19007437)
ORA-01110: data file 10: '\UDR''
```

unfortunately all this long the database was in no archive log mode as now I know. So further investigating I found out that this block is in partition 9 of the table which holds 9th of Feb data.

So how can I recover from this issue? I try to to validate the blocks from rman and then try to recover it, but I get message that there is no back up for that since my db was in no archivelog mode

any help to either ignore it while running query or if I drop the data of 9th feb and reload them will that fix the issue?

when I do

```
select * from v$database_block_corruption

file | block# | blocks | corruption_change# | corruption_type |cond_id
10 | 1 | 19007437| 0 | fractured | 0
```

when I select the block from dba_extents then I see

```
segment_name | segment_type | block_id
tablename | partitionname | 19007437
```

Comment: go to metalink and search for note called "How to format corrupted data block"

Comment: hi unfortunately I don't have support for metalink

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to tell Oracle to ignore a bad block. I think your idea of dropping the partition and reloading is about the best you can do.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when in RMAN you issue `blockrecoverer datafile 10 block 19007437;`?